# I want to read how much does my program uses resources in unix but cant

Tags: linux, unix, cl

I have program that I need to run and then see how much resources it uses in unix by using top command. But I don't know how to do it because if i run it from command line I cant use top command till program is finished and vice versa. How can I do it. I tried doing:

```
sleep 10s
top
./myProgram
```

But its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open two terminals; run your program in one terminal and top in another.

- If you're in a graphical environment, you can just start the terminal a second time.
- If you're on the text-only console, you can switch between terminals using Ctrl-Alt-F1..F6 (possibly more) or Alt-Left/Right.
- If you connect via SSH, just open multiple terminal sessions in your SSH client.

(Also, I'd hint to use htop instead of top, but you may need to install it first.)

In case your program is too short-lived to show up on top/htop, you might need to run it using [Valgrind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valgrind).

Answer (score 1):

Open two terminals one for running top, and run your program in the other.

Comment: how can i open 2 terminals in virtual machine

Comment: @T0milicaVeršić Using Ctrl-Alt-F1..F6, if you've got a "server installation" without GUI in your VM.